# How to run scheduled task without scheduled task on web server

Tags: asp.net

My client has changed web hosting. On old web hosting there was option to run scheduled task. I have one url website.com/st.aspx that needs to be runed once per month.

On new web server there is no scheduled task (it is not working and admin will not enable it) is there any other way for me to run my url like ST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and use an on-line service

```
http://http.sh/index.php
```

Of course the down side is you are reliant on a 3rd party but it seems to be pretty reliable.

Comment: I will use this tnx for link.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it from an **other server** which has scheduled tasks enabled.

Or, if you're website gets at least some traffic, you could call whatever is executed in `st.aspx` from **`global.asax`** and log somewhere when you called it the last time to prevent calling it more than once a month.

An other possibility would be to try to find an **uptime monitoring service** which you can configure to call only once a month your url...